# Peculiarities of translating the gerund in civil law documents

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, gerunds

I'm writing a thesis and I've been given this subject: peculiarities of translating the gerund in civil law documents. How can I extend this subject?

Comment: I don't believe this is the right site to consult for this matter since your question is about arguments and contents.

Comment: The whole point of a thesis is you come up with the fundamental ideas and organization for yourself, and then execute against that. That’s the key skill the exercise is intended to impart to you. You can’t outsource it.